# Null exception in TabbedPage with FormsAppCompatActivity

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The error I'm getting is very useless:

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
[MonoDroid] at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61
[MonoDroid] at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1006
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.SyncContext/<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:18
[MonoDroid] at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
[MonoDroid] at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:71
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.51b21b24-f225-4055-ba6f-89c907c5f353 (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0001f>
```

When I load a TabbedPage, I can see the tabs being displayed then this crash happens.

Here is my Tabs.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
/>
```

Here is how I set it:

```
        FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting a "useless" stack trace is likely due to an exception being thrown from an async void method. There is an issue in the Mono framework that causes that to occur. For more information on that see [this bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=30513).

If you need an accurate stack trace you could try upgrading Xamarin.Android to the Alpha channel (I believe the stack trace issue is fixed there).

If you are unable to do that, you could try setting breakpoints in any async void methods that are run during the tab initialization or OnAppearing of the pages and try to narrow down which method/line the exception is being thrown on.

Comment: That's really interesting, I actually noticed this issue before but was too stupid to investigate further. What if I change all async void to async Task? I'll check.

Comment: man... I want to give you special thanks, you saved the hair left in my balding head. I found the issue, it was indeed happening in an async void method OnAppear. The reason it's async void is because it's overriding OnAppear in parent which must be void but I want to do async stuff in it. Thank you, my friend :)